# Kubernetes dashboard: How to access more than 15 minutes of CPU and memory usage in the Web UI dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The web UI dashboard (which is rendered by running 'kubectl proxy') is very useful and gives a great highlevel overview of the cluster. However the CPU and memory usage graphs seems to be hardcoded to display only the last 15 minutes. I am not able to find any settings that allows me to increase this, nor could I find any documentation on how to do this. Our team is exploring setting up grafana/influxdb and other services to get more detailed metrics, but it will be nice if there is an option to increase the timeline to the webui dashboard.

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible out of the box. You could fork and edit the dashboard, but using an external tool (Prometheus+grafana) would be just easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible as of version 2.4.0 (maybe even earlier versions, I did not check the exact version where the feature was implemented).

For dashboard version 2, it is as simple as changing the metrics scraper configuration to larger `--metric-duration` values. If you are using official Helm charts for deployment:

```yaml
metricsScraper:
  enabled: true
  args:
    - --metric-duration=2h
    - --metric-resolution=5m
```

Otherwise, adapt this info to your current deployment scenario.